# Sprite not moving in the same direction it is facing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have an issue with my sprite not moving in the same direction as it is facing. It is top view of a beetle, 10 images animating its leg movements. The sprite animation works fine, choosing new 'random' direction by rotating the image and re-centering to previous center is working too.

What I can't get to work is the sprite to move 'forward', that is to move in the new direction it chooses/faces every second or so. The new direction is simply a small 10-15 degrees rotation left or right from previous position. Instead it moves in what seem like random movements every time the sprite chooses a new direction. For example it will move southwest while facing east, or move north while facing south etc.

I suspect the problem is in the move() method where the movement isn't properly translated via trig values. I am adding to the rect.x values because it is the same as the cartesian coords system while subtracting from rect.y values because it is inverted in pygame compared to cartesian. Going down is increasing positively, up - decreasing y values, increasing negatively.

The class for the beetle sprite is below:

```
class Foe():
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.sprites = []
        for i in range(1, 11):
            file = pg.image.load("beetleprac1/000"+str(i)+"a.png").convert()  # 10 sprite files named "0001a-10a.png" last 1 is idle stance
            #file.set_colorkey((0, 255, 255))
            self.sprites.append(file)
        self.move_anim_index = 9
        self.image = self.sprites[self.move_anim_index]
        self.rotated_image = self.image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=location)
        self.move_rect_coords = [self.rect.x, self.rect.y]
        self.angle = 90
        self.speed = 3
        self.time = 0
        self.frames_counter = 0


    def move_anim(self, rate=2): # rate is in frames
        if self.frames_counter % rate == 0:
            self.move_anim_index += 1
            if self.move_anim_index >= 9:
                self.move_anim_index = 0
            self.image = self.sprites[self.move_anim_index]
            #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
            self.rotated_image = self.image.copy()
            self.rotated_image = pg.transform.rotate(self.image, self.angle - 90)
            self.rect = self.rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


    def move(self, last_tick):
        self.move_anim()   
        self.rect.x += int(self.speed * math.cos(self.angle)) 
        self.rect.y -= int(self.speed * math.sin(self.angle))
        self.move_rect_coords = [self.rect.x, self.rect.y]


    def change_direction(self, change_time): # change_time in frames
        if self.frames_counter % change_time == 0: 
            a = random.choice([-1, 1])
            self.angle += 15
            if self.angle < 0: self.angle += 360
            if self.angle > 360: self.angle -=360

        #if self.rect.x <  



    def track_time(self, last_tick, amount):
        self.time += last_tick
        self.frames_counter += 1
        if self.time >= last_tick * amount:
            self.time = 0
            self.counter = 0


    def think(self, last_tick):
        self.track_time(last_tick, FPS*2)
        self.change_direction(FPS)


    def update(self, last_tick, screen_rect):
        self.think(last_tick)
        self.move(last_tick)


    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.rotated_image, self.move_rect_coords)
```

And here is the full code and repository at github: https://github.com/fn88/buganimprac2

Comment: use `print()` to check what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It helps to find problem.

Comment: `sin()` and `cos()` need radians - `cos(math.radians(angle))`

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it.

Comment: Sidenote: You can remove the line `self.rotated_image = self.image.copy()`, since `pg.transform.rotate` returns a new surface and doesn't modify the original. Also, I suggest to take a look at [pygame sprites](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13) and I think [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) could also help you.

Answer (score 1):

`sin()`, `cos()` and other trigonometric functions use `radians` ->  `cos(math.radians(angle))`